# Why does init method set this ivar to (null)?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, instance-variables, init

I don't understand why adding the `init` method to my view controller sets some ivars to `(null)` when some data are passed to this controller. Here's the code I use to set some ivar values and call the associated view controller:

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
vc.search_type = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"buy"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
```

In `MyViewController`, the `search_type` ivar contains the `@"buy"` string stored in the previous view controller as expected. However, when I add the `init` method below, `search_type` always contains a `(null)` string when I try to use it in `MyViewController`:

```
(id)init
{
   self = [super init];
   if(self)
   {
        // some other code here
   }
   return self;
}
```

search_type is declared in interface as:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableString *search_type;
```

and synthesize in implementation file:

```
@synthesize search_type;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but if you are saying that `search_type` is nil in your `init` method where you have placed `// some other code here`, that's because your view controller is initialised before you set that property.

If you need to supply that object to your view controller before some more code runs, you have several options:

- Create a custom initialiser such as `initWithSearchType:`.
- Create a custom setter for that property.
- Execute the code in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` or similar method.

Which of these is appropriate depends on exactly what it is you are doing.

Comment: what I'm trying to do is just pass search_type value to another controller but when I add the init method the passed value seems cleared somewhere as when I try to use the search_type it now contains an empty string "" if I alloc/init search type in init method or (null) if not

Comment: Post the code where you try to use `search_type` and post your full `init` method.

Comment: init method contains search_type = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; then in viewDidLoad I just make NSLog(@"search_type=%@",search_type); and it prints search_type="" with empty string

Answer (score 0):

search_type is mutable, do you init in the init method of MyViewController?

Comment: search_type is mutable but I didn't init it. Should I ?

Comment: Yes, if is a mutable you should

Comment: the only thing that changed is now search_type contains empty string "" instead of (null)

Comment: In the header of MyViewController the search_type is a propertly?

Comment: I got -1 because i try to help

Comment: dont know who gave you -1 but I just gave you +1!

Comment: thanks, the edit in the firs post should work well if you init search_type too

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing the instance variable in this code

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
MyViewController.search_type = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"buy"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
```

You create an instance named `vc` but are not using it. Try this instead:

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
vc.search_type = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"buy"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
```

HTH.

**Update**

It's hard to tell what the problem is in the code you've shared. My other guess based on what you've shared would be to make sure that you defined your property and synthesized it correctly.

```
// in the header file
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSMutableString *search_type;

// in your implementation
@synthesize search_type = m_search_type;
```

If you've done that, you should probably share more of your `MyViewController` source. It doesn't matter whether or not you initialize the variable in your `init` method, because you're assigning it a new value after you instantiate it anyway.

Comment: I just made a mistake when typing to stackoverflow...thx anyway :)

Comment: Updated answer with another idea. Mind sharing more?

Comment: `NS[Mutable]String` properties (or any class with a mutable subclass) should generally be declared `(copy)` so that you're not sharing a mutable object.

Comment: got the poing with "copy" as I was using retain I'm going to test it But where does the "m_search_type" in your code comes from ?

Comment: That just assigns a name to the generated ivar. Check out http://shinydevelopment.com/blog/automatic-property-instance-variables-with-objective-c/